# Why do this bash script do not see slurm log file when it appears?

Tags: bash, filesystems, slurm

I wanted to create a little script to display slurm output on a cluster without having to wait. It almost works except that I have to do an ls (or other disk access) in the same folder in another shell for the display to start. I don't understand why. Here is the script :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

LOG=$(sbatch $1 | awk '{print $4}')
i=1
declare -a progress=("/" "-" "\\" "-")
while [ ! -f res_${LOG}.log ]; do
    /bin/echo -n -e "Waiting for res_${LOG}.log to appear ${progress[$((${i} % 4))]} \r"
    i=$((${i}+1))
    sleep 1
done
echo
tail -f res_${LOG}.log
```

Note that it starts the given command using `sbatch` and then repeatedly checks if the slurm log file has appeared which means the job has been started. Unfortunately, the while loop never exits if I don't do a file system access in another shell or in the script. If I add

```sh
ls >& /dev/null
```

just after the `sleep 1`, the loop exits as expected as soon as the log file appears.

The minimal example below has the problem. Called `wait.slurm`, I execute it with `./sbatch.sh wait.slurm`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
 
#SBATCH --output=res_%j.log
 
while [ 1 ]; 
        do echo hello;
        sleep 1;
done
```

I suspect some weird thing at the filesystem level, but I'd like to understand what it is.

Comment: can you give a minimal example of script you submit to it ? In particular the `#SBATCH -o`. The file name `res_${job-id}` is not standard, it is usually rather `slurm-${job_id}.out` (you get the job id from the slurm script ?)

Comment: This minimal example has the problem. Called `wait.slurm`, I execute it with `./sbatch.sh wait.slurm`.
```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
#SBATCH --output=res_%j.log
 
while [ 1 ]; 
        do echo hello;
        sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: @xiawi I edited the question with the minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is on a network filesystem (e.g. NFS). Several mechanisms can be at play here:

- the filesystem client on the submission node can have a cache mechanism where queries about the filesystem are made faster by keeping the information in a local memory and updating every minute or so ;
- the filesystem client on the compute node can have a buffering mechanism where writes are grouped into larger sets of write operations to avoid many small writes in favour of fewer larger writes to make the operation faster  ;
- the filesystem server can be configured to also have buffers and caches.

Running the `ls` command appears to force the filesystem to synchronise its operations (flush buffers, invalidate caches).

You can try to call the `sync` system call from the compute node. E.g. in your example

```
#!/bin/bash
 
#SBATCH --output=res_%j.log
 
while [ 1 ]; 
        do echo hello;
        sync
        sleep 1;
done
```

A better way though would probably to use the [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) command if it is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You're right, there is networked file systems here but I don't know which exactly. I tried the `sync` solution but it did not work. I even tried to sync also in the caller but it did not change anything. And inotifywait is not installed. I can ask the admin to install it if necessary.